# PHP echo not returning <div> correctly

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

Can someone tell me why the `<?php echo $userPasswordError; ?>` line returns nothing (empty) instead of `<div class="invalid-feedback">Too long.</div>` when I enter a password which contain more than 1 character with the below code ?

If I change this line : `$userPasswordError = '<div class="invalid-feedback">Too long.</div>';`

with this `$userPasswordError = 'Too long.';` , it works ! Output is "Too long.".

```
<?php
$user = $userPassword = '';
$userError = $userInvalid = $userPasswordError = $userPasswordInvalid = '';
$isvalidOrInvalidUser = $isvalidOrInvalidUserPassword = '';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // Verify username.
  if (!empty($_POST["user"])) {
    if (strlen($_POST["user"]) <= 32) {
      $user = $_POST["user"];
      $userError = '<div class="valid-feedback">Correct.</div>';
      $isvalidOrInvalidUser = 'is-valid';
    }
    else {
      $userInvalid = $_POST["user"];
      $userError = '<div class="invalid-feedback">Too long.</div>';
      $isvalidOrInvalidUser = 'is-invalid';
    }
  }
  else {
    $userError = '<div class="invalid-feedback">Please, add username.</div>';
    $isvalidOrInvalidUser = 'is-invalid';
  }
  // Verify password.
  if (!empty($_POST["userpassword"])) {
    if (strlen($_POST["userpassword"]) <= 1) {
      $userPassword = $_POST["userpassword"];
      $userPasswordError = '<div class="valid-feedback">Correct.</div>';
      $isvalidOrInvalidUserPassword = 'is-valid';
    }
    else {
      $userPasswordInvalid = $_POST["userpassword"];
      $userPasswordError = '<div class="invalid-feedback">Too long.</div>';
      $isvalidOrInvalidUserPasword = 'is-invalid';
    }
  }
  else {
    $userPasswordError = '<div class="invalid-feedback">Please, add password.</div>';
    $isvalidOrInvalidUserPassword = 'is-invalid';
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="user">Username :</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control <?php echo $isvalidOrInvalidUser; ?>" id="user" name="user" placeholder="User here" value="<?php echo $user.$userInvalid; ?>">
      <?php echo $userError; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="userpwd">User password :</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control <?php echo $isvalidOrInvalidUserPassword; ?>" id="userpassword" name="userpassword" value="<?php echo $userPassword.$userPasswordInvalid; ?>">
      <?php echo $userPasswordError; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me https://3v4l.org/GYMqD Perhaps the `invalid-feedback` class has a `display: none`?

Comment: No for the display:none. And it works correctly for the username if I enter one which is greater than 32 characters (same "div class" is called). I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally know why.

```
  $userPasswordError = '<div class="invalid-feedback">Too long.</div>';
  $isvalidOrInvalidUserPasword = 'is-invalid';
```

The variable name of `isvalidOrInvalidUserPasword` is wrong, it should be `$isvalidOrInvalidUserPassword` (missing an `s` at Pasword).

If the input does not have class `is-invalid`, the error message will not visible!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Damn it... Thank you very much.